# Make PDO connection utf8 encoded

Tags: mysql, pdo, encoding

I am trying to encode my connection to become UTF8. I was looking at some other posts, but soe some reason it doesnt work. No idea what I am doing wrong.

**This is how my conn looks**

```
 $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
```

**And this is what I am trying to do**, but it says that is not correct

```
 $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password.";charset=utf8");
```

**Gives this error**
Database Connection Error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for

I am using MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your charset before the user and password.

```
$this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" .
     $this->host .
     ";dbname="  . $this->db_name .
     ";charset=utf8" ,
     $this->username,
     $this->password);
```

Comment: Wow, that was so simple

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be part of the first argument.  Your second version should look like this:

```
$this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name.";charset=utf8", $this->username, $this->password);
```

The error you're getting is because your password is wrong (you're appending ";charset=utf8" to the password, and your password likely does not end with that).